# javascript back to last active div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: main div]

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tabbale">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs " style="width:70%;">
    <li><a href="#Prof" data-toggle="tab" class="w3-hover-white w3-xlarge"><b>Profile </b></a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#MainFree" data-toggle="tab" class="w3-hover-white w3-xlarge"><b>Account</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#MainPrem" data-toggle="tab" class="w3-hover-white w3-xlarge"><b>Report</b></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="Prof">
    user image
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="MainFree">
    <center>
      <p>You have not any account yet, click <a href='ModSel.php' target='_parent' style='text-decoration:none;' class='w3-text-teal'>here</a> to add.</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="MainPrem">
    <center>
      Result
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have this dilemma where I need to back to previous active tab, as you can see on above picture, whenever the page is loaded user will see the **Profile** div, and whenever they've click on any of those, says, **Account** then the account div will be active and shown up like belows image. as you can see, id user click **here** (I'm using href) in this **div**, it will be navigated to other page, that works fine.

[image: account div]

The issue is, let's say that user want to get back to this page from last activity, or maybe attempt to refresh this page. How do I get back to the last active div, in this case **Account**.

besides, i've also tried the anchor hash method from other page so it could get back to the last active div. which is like **sites.com#MainFree** but still not work for me.

Comment: You'll have to show your code. We can't know how the tabs work just by looking at pictures of them.

Comment: added already..hope u'll understand the short of the code..

Comment: You are including jQuery twice in your code, might make issues for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution along with `localStorage` https://jsfiddle.net/jq5d73de/

```js
if(localStorage.getItem('setActiveTab') != 'null'){
  $('a[href="' + localStorage.getItem('setActiveTab') + '"]').click();
}

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function(){
  localStorage.setItem('setActiveTab', $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="tabbale">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs " style="width:70%;">
    <li><a href="#Prof" data-toggle="tab" class="w3-hover-white w3-xlarge"><b>Profile </b></a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#MainFree" data-toggle="tab" class="w3-hover-white w3-xlarge"><b>Account</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#MainPrem" data-toggle="tab" class="w3-hover-white w3-xlarge"><b>Report</b></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="Prof">
    user image
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="MainFree">
    <center>
      <p>You have not any account yet, click <a href='ModSel.php' target='_parent' style='text-decoration:none;' class='w3-text-teal'>here</a> to add.</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="MainPrem">
    <center>
      Result
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could update the url and put a get parameter in it, so the url will be
site.com/page?section=account

And once a user reloads the page, select the correct section either by getting the parameter in JS or getting the parameter in PHP and modifying it there.

Comment: i've tried doing this but still  the **Profile** div is shown first, which is that is the one that been set defaultly as active.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cookie to store the last active section. Update the cookie whenever the active section changes. Read from that cookie when you render the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) to set the url. Then use [window.location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) to get the hash from the URL on load and last use the `hashchange` event if the user uses the back button while it's on the page:

```
$("[data-state]").click(function (event) {
    history.pushState(null, null, "#" + $(event.currentTarget).data("state"));
    refreshSelection();
    event.preventDefault();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    refreshSelection();
});

$(window).on('hashchange', function () {
    refreshSelection();
});

function refreshSelection() {
    if (document.location.hash) {
        $("[data-state]").css("font-weight", "normal");
        $("[data-state=" + document.location.hash.replace("#", "") + "]").css("font-weight", "bold");
    }
}
```

You won't be able to see the url change in this fiddle, but here is the working example https://jsfiddle.net/m5cfL8p4/